# Can we merge with "Martial Arts" with "Sports"?

Tags: discussion

In the past several sports have been merged with Sports@SE. I for sure do not intend practicing martial arts as a sport (but some people might practice what I call sport with the spirit with which I practice martial arts).

Given our low stats, we could benefit from their level of activity.

What do you think? What would be the disadvantages?

Comment: Many of the various sports on Area 51 were all merged into the Sports proposal long before Sports had launched into beta.

Answer (score 3):

1. We are not the only group to ask about that, since we have questions right now that are likely to be off-topic at Sports.SE.
2. Martial arts has its own culture independent of what most people classify as "sports."  Regardless of our ability to attract experts here, it seems even less likely that such will garner expert feedback on a sports stack exchange.   You can see a manifestation of that based on how few MA-oriented questions there are on Sports.SE and the character of those questions versus the ones here.

Comment: Agreed. Some questions would fit better on Fitness.SE if the site were shut down, but I'm not so sure Martial Arts would fit well in Sports. It could, but I think the subset of questions would probably be small anyway.